# Partial differential equation with initial conditions

Tags: differential-equations

And so I want to solve the following equation, subject to these initial conditions:

$\ u_{tt} - u_{xx} = 6u^5+(8+4a)u^3-(2+4a)u$

$\ u(0,x)=\tanh(x), u_t(0,x)=0$

When I use NDSolve to solve within the intervals $\ [0,10] \times [-5,5]$, I tried this as a code:

```
NDSolve[{
   D[u[t, x], t, t] - D[u[t, x], x, x] ==
     6 u[t, x]^5 + (8+4a) u[t, x]^3 - (2+4a) u[t, x],
   u[0, x] == Tanh[x], D[u[0, x], t] == 0},
 u[t, x], {t, 0, 10}, {x, -5, 5}]
```

But Mathematica then returns the following line:

```
NDSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of True in the first argument
```

where the `True` affirmation seemingly refers to the second initial condition. What is it that I did wrong? Is there anything wrong with the code? Is there anything wrong with the problem?

Comment: `D[u[0, x], t] == 0` is trivially true because `u[0,x]` does not depend on `t`.  To write the equation you mention, write it as `Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x]`.  As a beginner as yet unfamiliar with `Derivative`, you could have constructed this expression as `D[u[t, x], t] /. t -> 0`, i.e. take the derivative *first*, and substitute the value `t=0` only afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `u[x,0]` does not depend on `t` differentiating leads to `0==0`. It should be `Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x] == 0`  Also for your problem  one needs some boundary conditions.

Comment: Now I'd love to be able to compute a numerical integral of the solution, or a function thereof...